# Как показать реальное время, если оно неправильное на компьютере?

Tags: c#, winforms, api, время, datetime

возник такой вопрос : А что если допустим на компе у владельца неправильное время, тогда получается нужно его откуда-то выудить, может аля есть какие-то фичи или API для того чтобы достать реальное время?
P.S. Обновить время с компа или обновить его с помощью открытия cmd и вписывания туда команд(те еще костыли) не предлагать, я ищу альтернативу

Comment: Получить с NTP-сервера.

Comment: Если компьютер не подключён к интернету, ему неоткуда узнать «правильное» время

Comment: Компьютер подключен к интернету

Comment: [api c Гугл мапс](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro)

Comment: а получить время от сервера? Из того же API.

Comment: Есть сервера точного (атомного) времени к которым можно обратиться. Раньше они были платные, а теперь наверное и бесплатные есть. Через GPS/Глонасс можно получить точное время. Через сотовую сеть (если не отключено).

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попытаюсь реализовать все вышеперечисленное

Comment: Еще в Кельне стоит радиостанция на СВ, которая шлет сигналы точного времени. Но до России, вроде бы, не добивает.

Answer (score 0):

Этот метод достает время с  [NIST Internet Time Service](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/its.cfm)

```
var client = new TcpClient("time.nist.gov", 13);
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
{
    var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var utcDateTimeString = response.Substring(7, 17);
    var localDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(utcDateTimeString, "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
}
```

Взят с: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435207/4423545

---

А вот этот метод должен работать так же с google.com,yahoo.com и msdn.com. Используй какой нравится на свой выбор. Возвращает GMT, на сколько я понял.

```
public static DateTime GetNistTime()
{
    var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
    var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];
    return DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates, 
                               "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, 
                               DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
}
```

Код взят отсюда: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/36981876/4423545**

---

Ответы найдены по запросу в гугл: "c# get current time form internet"